# .Net Reformat data in the List of List of Sting

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I have a List(Of List(Of String).

list contains data like this:

```
item-A1 item-A2 item-A3
item-B1 item-B2 item-B3
item-C1 item-C2 item-C3
```

I would like to somehow change it to this:

```
item-A1 item-B1 item-C1
item-A2 item-B2 item-C2
item-A3 item-B3 item-C3
```

Is there a way to reformat data and shown in the example ? 
any hints would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you thought about using a [Dictionary](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=dictionary+c%23&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=HdJRVbPkH6T5ygO_jIHwBA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            List<List<string>> lstStrings = new List<List<string>>{
               new List<string>() {"A1","A2","A3"},
               new List<string> {"B1","B2","B3"},
               new List<string> {"C1","C2","C3"}
                };
                List<List<string>> newList = new List<List<string>>();
                int j=0;
                 foreach(String s in lstStrings[0])
                 {

                     List<string> innerList = new List<string>();
                     for(int i=0;i<lstStrings.Count;i++)
                    {
                        innerList.Add(lstStrings[i][j]);    
                    }
                    j++;
                    newList.Add(innerList);
            }
            foreach(List<string> lstInner in newList)
            {
                foreach(string s in lstInner)
                {
                    Console.Write(s);    
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Output

A1B1C1

A2B2C2

A3B3C3